# Intel XDK hide Status bar

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, intel-xdk

I have made an app with IntelXDk, and I want to hide the status bar.
In the app.js file I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener("intel.xdk.device.ready",function(){ 
    intel.xdk.device.hideStatusBar();
},false);
```

But when the app start on my android device the status bar is still visible.

What am I doing wrong.

btw I have installed the plugin Intel XDk Device and just for test the index.html file it only contains a header and  nothing else.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the link in the top left corner,

[image]

Then check the fullscreen option,

[image]

**Images courtesy of Google.**

Then when you build the APK it will be in fullscreen.